# Use variables in the cursor command "SELECT x FROM y"

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I have been trying to create a function that with input of the column name, tablename, start ID and end ID, recreate the desired table from the MYSQL Server connected with python.I have mainly two problems,
fist the line `mycursor.execute("SELECT colNames FROM tablename")` doesn't understand variables like colNames and tablename it only gets the exact name of columns and table names. I want to be able to call a table by manually inputting variables. My second problem is the the function to show only rows starting from `StartId` and ending with `EndId`, and for that i don't know how to modify the for loop to do this for me in this context.

This is for a the mysql package in python and i need to extract a specified column in order to start a machine learning process on it ( periodicity detection, feature extraction, feature selection etc.)

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    database='feldbuslogging',
    user='root',
    password='xxx'
)


def readFromTable(connection, tablename, colNames, startId, endId):
    tablename = input("Input Tablename: ")
    colNames = input("Input Column Name: ")
    startId = input("Input Start ID: ")
    endId = input("Input End ID: ")
    startId = int(startId)
    endId = int(endId)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT colNames FROM tablename")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult(startId: endId):
        print(x)
```

I expect the output to be a new table with the desired variables and rows starting from `StartId` and ends with `EndId`.

- `for x in myresult(startId:endId)` gets `invalid Syntax`

  - I suppose that's not exactly how to put it.
- `mycursor.execute("SELECT colNames FROM tablename")` gets `feldbuslogging.tablename` does not exist.

Comment: `mycursor.execute("SELECT colNames FROM tablename")` Because this is all in a literal string, this selects a column actually named `colNames` -- it does not use the variable named that.

Comment: `for x in myresult(startId:endId)` If you're trying to use slice notation, use square brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: since it is all in a literal string, what do i modify/implement in order for it to select my variables? Or is a function here in this context not possible? and thanks for the hint for the brackets instead of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Just for you question. If your start id and end id is the primary key id.

you can do simple modify like follows(Not Safe):

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute(
    "SELECT {col} FROM {tbl} WHERE id>=%s AND id<%s".format(
        col=colNames, tbl=tablename
    ),
    (startId, endId)
)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
    print(x)
```

BTW, you should read the library documentation first.

You can get easily find this.

- [mysql-connector-python](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python)
- [Querying Data Using Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html)

**UPDATE**

As @John Gordon said. The code above is not safe for col name and table name are entered by the user.

If you do this at production. Need to do more inspections.

Comment: `colNames` and `tablename` are entered by the user, so this answer is terribly unsafe.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder.  This answer not consider this. Just show simple usage for use variable. :)

Comment: may i know why is this answer unsafe please? im relatively new to mysql

Comment: @SeifeddineS'hili as your code, the variable is entered by user.  So user can build malicious SQL statements to improve roles. If you want to get more information. search `SQL injection` on google.  Like `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection`.

Comment: @IkarosKun thanks for your answers , last question , how do i modify the code written above , if the end-user wants to input more than a column ?

Comment: You can  let the col param to  comma-separated list.  Such as  col1,col2,col3   .